# alternative method rotate of scipy.ndimage

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I use python 3.6 and scipy.

Is there an alternative function rotate of scipy.ndimage and
how would they be called?

I need a function, which is performater than that of scipy.ndimage.rotate and they also uses a interpolation.

```
import scipy.ndimage as sn
sn.rotate(array, theta, reshape=False, order=3)
```

This is only a example.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For rotating images, there are many options. Hereafter are a few ones:

- With OpenCV: [Here is a tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/). The function is `cv2.rotate`
- With pillow (PIL): [Here is a tutorial](http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/patterns/p0201/).

  `from PIL import Image
  img = Image.open("image.png")
  rotated_img2 = img.rotate(10)  # angle = 10`
- With Scipy, there is another function: `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate`.
- Also Scikit-image (`skimage`) has its own rotation function: `skimage.transform.rotate`